Finding a movie about a girl who kissed her bff during school while she was drunk and asks him to forget about it
if you can help me to find what is the name of the movie with the next plot i will be grateful:
A girl kisses her BFF while she was drunk and day after she is very shy about it and asks him to forget it like it never happened , then instead of asking her to prom he asks the another girl from their school , After that i remember that the girl had sex with her prom partner without a condom and the condom got stuck in her so she called her BFF to help her (and she gets pregmanet eventually from that accident)
There were many things going on after that but i remember close to the end of the movie the girl bought a place and made a Hotel out of it and eventually they meet again and become together.
Movie is in color - i believe pretty new 2000+ 
American most likely hollywood
Also at the end the daughther of this girl also has a BFF and she kisses him , but after she is being very ashamed and running to her mother and he new husband (her old bff) and says that she will tell him that it was a mistake and will ask him to forget about it , but her mother and "father" says not to do it and she probably really loves him (Also they dont want her to go through what they went only because the girl said to her best friend that the kiss was a mistake in the begging of the movie) 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

@Paulie_D Add some more information , i believe the actors are pretty famous but i cant remember any of their name because i seen the movie long time ago

After i could remember one of the charters was playing in the Hunger games i was able to find the movie , its called - Love Rosie for whoever interested , its really nice :)

You might want to elaborate in which way it fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

The movie is a British-German romantic comedy-drama film- Love, Rosie (2014). It is based on 2004 novel Where Rainbows End by Cecelia Ahern. The film stars Lily Collins, Sam Claflin, Tamsin Egerton, Suki Waterhouse, Jaime Winstone and Lily Laight. The movie revolves around two high school bffs Alex and Rosie. 


Rosie Dunne and Alex Stewart have been best friends since they were little kids. The movie opens on Rosie sitting alone looking dejected at a table, while wedding guests mingle around her. It then cuts to the past, and Rosie and Alex are at a bar. They are celebrating Rosie's 18th birthday, and share a drunken, passionate kiss before Rosie falls off a stool and hits her head, knocking herself out. She wakes up the next morning with no recollection of the night before, but Alex doesn't realize she doesn't remember their kiss. Rosie tells Alex she wishes that night had never happened and doesn't want to talk about it ever again, which he takes as a sign of her rejection.
Later on Rosie and Alex attend a bonfire on a beach, where they discuss the upcoming school dance. Rosie reveals she had been asked by Greg, the "fittest guy in school", but she turned him down because she and Alex had already planned to go together. Meanwhile, Alex has set his sights on a blonde named Bethany, who Rosie says might be hard to get due to the fact that Alex is still a virgin. He laughs it off, confidently telling Rosie how Bethany had wanted to go to the dance with him. Rosie suggests he take Bethany, and she take Greg. Alex agrees. The day of the dance Alex breaks the news that "virgin boy is no longer" to Rosie, adding that he lost it to Bethany. She looks unhappy for a few moments, but brushes it aside. That night Alex drives Rosie to the hotel where the dance is held, where they split up; Alex with Bethany and Rosie with Greg. Each couple has a great time on the dance floor, though Rosie and Alex sneak each other longing glances. Later on Rosie and Greg head up to a room, where their night doesn't exactly go as planned when Greg's condom falls off and becomes stuck inside Rosie. After Greg ditches her she calls Alex, who is still downstairs dancing with Bethany. He leaves Bethany to drive Rosie to the hospital where a male nurse removes the condom for her, though not without some awkward tension.

Above is a portion of the plot synopsis describing the events in the question.
